# Enumerable and Dense

Tags: general-topology

I'm starting in topology! Something I'm not finding is the relation between enumerability and density, my question is, "A set being dense implies not being enumerable"?

Comment: Famously $\Bbb Q$ is a dense countable subset of $\Bbb R$ (in its usual topology).

Comment: Example of dense and not enumerable is $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$. A dense set can be both enumerable and non-enumerable.

Comment: If X is a topological space then X is a dense subset of X regardless of whether X is countable. The density d(X) is the least infinite cardinal  K such that X has a dense subset whose cardinal is at most K. If X does not have a finite dense subset then d(X) is the least cardinal K such that X has a dense subset of cardinality K. Density is one of many topological cardinal functions: Cardinals associated with a topology

Answer (score 1):

Density does not imply that a set is enumerable or uncountable. A subset $E$ of a topological space $X$ is dense if every $x \in X$ is either in $E$ or is a limit point of $E$ (equivalently, if $\overline{E} = X$). The most common example you'll see of this is that $\mathbb{Q}$ (which happens to be enumerable)  is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. However, $\mathbb{Q} \cup [0, 1]$ (with $[0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$) is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ but uncountable.